# Three recovery partitions on Windows 10 laptop. Can I safely remove some of them?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

[image: [This is map of my disk][1].]

Previously I had Windows 8.1 Single Language and upgrade to Windows 10 Home and after this upgrade to Windows 10 Education and now I have 3 recovery partitions. Could I safely remove some of this recovery partitions?

**UPD**: All of this partitions are totally clean

Comment: Yes. But the question is how to figure out which 2 to remove ;)

Comment: Are any ways to detect which one is currently in use?

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me I remove all recovery partitions and all works well for this two weeks.

Answer (score 1):

(I can't comment due to rep).

FYI - Recovery partitions are not for keeping your OS running, they are for recovering your OS if something goes wrong.

I.E. If something is corrupt, the company you purchased the machine from will have their own recovery partition and disk for performing repairs/formatting to the OS.

I would highly recommend only removing them if you're comfortable with recovering Windows and have the appropriate utilities/software to hand should something come up.

Short answer: You can remove them all. Long Answer: See above.